# See if div contains another div with a particular class?

Tags: jquery, css

Say I have:

```
<div class="outer">

<div class="foo bar"></div>

</div>
```

How can I check to see if `$('.outer')` has a div with a class named "bar" within it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

```
$('.outer:has(.bar)')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9bbM/).

This will select all elements with a class of `bar` with a `outer` ancestor.

If you have a reference to a collection selected with `$('.outer')`, you can drop ones which don't have the child element with `filter()` and `:has`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bzcB/).

If you have a reference to a `bar` and want to know if it has a `.outer` ancestor, you could do...

```
!!$('.bar:first').closest('.outer').length
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bzcB/).

Comment: Consider using the has method instead of the :has psuedo selector.  Rationale explained here: http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: So if I set the container to a variable such as `var outer = $('.outer');`, would I have to for a for (var key in outer) { stickyDiv[key]}, find the selector and add that in there, or is there an easier way? I'm trying to make this as modular as possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($("div.outer div.bar").length > 0){
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I you only have one class `outer` you could do:

```
if($('.outer > .bar').length) {
   // contains the .foo div
}
```

Answer (score 1):

children takes a selector

```
$('.outer').children('.bar').length > 0
```